# Where should a preposition be used in an interrogative sentence?

Tags: interrogatives

1. From where are you ? Or  where are you from?

2.At what time do you come ? Or
What time do you come at ?

Aren't the latter sentences in both the examples correct ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Where are you from?
- What time do you come?

Also, for the second one you can say:

- When do you come?

Comment: The first two of each pair are grammatically correct, but not at all natural in modern everyday speech. As Shayan says, _at_ is unnecessary in (2)